# React test case - get data from server before rendering

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

`App` component is

```
function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState({}); 

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/home")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(`got response ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
        return res.json();  //return json from res
      })
      .then((data) => { //data is the json returned previously. Promise chaining
        console.log(`data : ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);        
        setData(data) //override previous value of data object with value of received json object. 
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />

        {!data ? "No data received" : Object.keys(data).map(key => (
          <option key={key} value={key}>{data[key]}</option>)) 
        }
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

To test, it I have written this code

```
test('renders homepage', () => {
  render(<App />);
  const linkElement = screen.getByText("welcome");
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

I am getting error:

`TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: welcome. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.`

I am assuming it is because the component is not fetching data (`/home` ) from server. How do I get data from server (which is a simple object `{message : "welcome"}` before rendering the `App` component? Could I get data from server or do I need to mock or could I do both ?

Comment: Of course you don't want to get data from the real server. For one thing that's achingly slow from a low-level test perspective, and for another you can then only test what it currently returns (and not what happens if it responds differently, errors, etc.). Either mock fetch itself or use e.g. MSW to mock the network level: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Nov/22/js-tdd-e2e.html.

Comment: I appreciate the politeness you show when confirming what I intend to do. Not many do that. Thanks. I was hoping for both - real data server as well mocks for error cases. I do understand your point however.

Answer (score -1):

Your test likely doesn't know how to handle `fetch` with the API request by its own, hence it never got the response to display in the UI, causing the assertion to fail.

For your case, add a mock `fetch` to return the response that you desired (in this case `{message: 'welcome'}`) by adding --

```
global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
  Promise.resolve({
    json: () => Promise.resolve({ message: 'welcome }), // <-- mock response
  })
);

beforeEach(() => {
  fetch.mockClear();
});
```

Add those, and run the test again, and it should be working as you were hoping for now.

If that's not the case, the helpful utility function can help you identify what the current DOM looks like by running `screen.debug()`. Good luck!